# The curve has constant torsion.

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, self-learning

**Question:**

Show that when the curve $c_1=c_1(t)$ has constant torsion $\tau$, the curve $$c_2=c_2(t)=-\frac{1}{\tau}N+\int_{t_0}^{t}B(u)du$$
has constant curvature $-\tau$ or $+\tau$.

---

What I know:

$$\dot T=\kappa N$$
$$\dot{N}=-\kappa T +\tau B$$
$$\dot B=-\tau N$$

In fact, I posted what i did. But, I am not sure. There may be some mistakes.

[image]

Comment: To B11b:  Interesting question, but I suggest you edit it a bit; for example, don't you mean $\dot N = -\kappa T + \tau B$ etc.?  And shouldn't you have $c_2(t) = \frac{1}{\tau}N + \int_{t_0}^t B(u)du$?  I'll edit it if you like.  I'm concerned if you don't do these edits, the question is in danger of closure, which I don't think it deserves!  By the way, +1!

Comment: Dear @RobertLewis I Will be happy if you will correct :)

Comment: To B11b:  OK, I'm on it . . . let me know if I get it right, OK?

Comment: Okay okay @RobertLewis

Comment: To B11b:  Glad to help out!  Cheers!

Comment: By $c_1$ do you mean $c_2$?

Comment: No I dont know @francis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. Remember **unit** tangent $T=c_2^\prime$, so when you get $$c_2^\prime=\frac{\kappa}{\tau}T$$ simply do the substitution and get $$T=\frac{\kappa}{\tau}T$$ then square both sides: $$1=\left(\frac{\kappa}{\tau}\right)^2$$

Comment: I cannot understand what u said. Please can you explain more. $c'_2=\frac{\kappa t}{\tau}$ that's this equal to $T$.

Comment: I dont know how to conclude my solution.

Comment: @B11b: is it better now?

Comment: Then I need to write $\kappa=-\kappa^2 n-\ddot {n} $ right?

Comment: Sorry sorry I understand. Yeup:))